Does not show @User.Identity.Name after login in ASP.NET
I change my user table to Client and get some information in claim:
var claims = new List<Claim>
  {
      new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, client.ClientId.ToString()),
      new Claim(ClaimTypes.MobilePhone, client.MobileNumber),
      new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, client.Email),
      new Claim("ChefFoodIds", string.Join(",", login.ChefFoodIds))
  };

var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

var properties = new AuthenticationProperties
          {
              IsPersistent = login.RememberMe
          };

But I can not get some information from that for example the name of user in header in front of well come, or checking for authentication
Is it depend on changing the client table?
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
   <input type="hidden" id="isAuthenticated" name="IsAuthenticated" value="true" />

   <div class="nav-item dropdown">
       <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">Welcome @User.Identity.Name</a>
       <div class="dropdown-menu m-0 bg-secondary rounded-0">
           <a asp-controller="home" asp-action="AddToCart" asp-area="UserPanel" class="dropdown-item">User Panel</a>
           <a href="/Logout" class="dropdown-item">Exit</a>
       </div>
   </div>
}


you can find some idea for a solutions in this blog post I wrote: https://nestenius.se/2023/03/28/missing-openid-connect-claims-in-asp-net-core/

@User.Identity.Name return the "Name" claim of the user. But this code doesn't create this claim. Just Add following claim type will solve the problem.
new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, client.ClientId.ToString()),


Name is not unique, 2 users can both have same name.
NameIdentifer is generally unique GUID in database which is different for every user.
